# the data is still sent with a value null, when not checked

Tags: php, html

I have html form with checkbox. datalist is available in the datatable form, you can check some appropriate data and fill in the values. do not check if you don't use it. for example, I check row 1 and 3, when save, row 2 also sent,why?. Can someone help me?
Thanks

```
<form action="" method="POST">

<table border=1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-primary">
      <th>#</th>
      <th width="80px">Code</th>
      <th width="100px">Item</th>
      <th width="100px">Amount ($)</th>
      <th width="100px">Description</th>
      <th width="100px">Exp Limit ($)</th>
      <th width="100px">Exp Remaining ($)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="chkstruktur[]" value="550-0001">
      </td>
      <td>Meals</td>
      <td>
        <input name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount....">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="desc[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Desc....">
      </td>
      <td>50000</td>
      <td>45000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="chkstruktur[]" value="550-0002">
      </td>
      <td>Medicine</td>
      <td>
        <input name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount....">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="desc[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Desc....">
      </td>
      <td>100000</td>
      <td>25000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="chkstruktur[]" value="550-0003">
      </td>
      <td>Entertainment</td>
      <td>
        <input name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount....">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="desc[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Desc....">
      </td>
      <td>75000</td>
      <td>75000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>
```

Link : https://codepen.io/tyas_m/pen/OOqLpZ

The result is:

```
chkstruktur     ["550-0001", "550-0003"] -- this value is true
```

amount          ["100000", "", "50000"] -- why sent data with null value
desc            ["test1", "", "test3"] -- why sent data with null value

the result I want:

```
chkstruktur     ["550-0001", "550-0003"]
```

amount          ["100000", "50000"]
desc            ["test1", "test3"]

Answer (score 0):

Because the `amount` and `desc` are of type text and empty values are being sent. **Note:** It's an empty string not a `null` value.

Technically everything works as expected.

You need to re-build the HTML structure and to understand it. Instead of using `[]` I'd use the row count.

```
// Row 1
<input type="checkbox" name="chkstruktur[1]" class="check" value="550-0001">
<input type="text" name="amount[1]" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount....">
<input type="text" name="desc[1]" class="form-control" placeholder="Desc....">

// Row 2 and so on...
```

Then you can easily check values based on the key ( row count ) of `chkstruktur` checked items.

```
// Check if $_POST['chkstruktur'] exists
$items = isset($_POST['chkstruktur']) ? $_POST['chkstruktur'] : [];

if ($items) {
    foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
        $chkstruktur = $value;

        // Amount and desc will still need to be checked if exists.
        $amount = isset($_POST['amount'][$key]) ? $_POST['amount'][$key] : '';
        $desc = isset($_POST['desc'][$key]) ? $_POST['desc'][$key] : '';

        // Do something if these values
    }
}
```